# Paypal custom field value cut off sometimes

Tags: forms, paypal-ipn

I am having an issue with only partial custom data being passed through to Paypal from the `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="***">` field. I have tried everything from here, but can't reproduce a scenario where the custom field is not properly populated before form is posted to Paypal. Sorry to ask here, but I can't figure out why this is happening, and hoping someone has some idea.

From our web site, the custom field typically gets populated like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="name=myname&amp;email=me%40email.com&amp;item_id=2&amp;domain=mydomain.com&amp;amount_total=75.00&amp;amount_product=75.00">
```

Yet *sometimes* (emphasis on sometimes), the custom value returned from Paypal IPN contains only the first parameter `name=myname`. Other times, the full string is returned `name=myname&amp;email=me%40email.com&amp;item_id=2&amp;domain=mydomain.com&amp;amount_total=75.00&amp;amount_product=75.00`. This happens approximately 50/50, and it started about 1-2 weeks ago, without me being able to pinpoint exactly why or for what reason.

I can of course view this random issue also from our Paypal "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history" page. Some messages contain full custom string with multiple params, other messages contain *only* name parameter `name=myname`.

Does anyone have a good guess as to why this is happening? To be honest, I don't know where the issue lies, and it's hard to diagnose since it's random. I can't reproduce the issue from here.

Our payment page is here:
imagevuex.com/buy/

Comment: you should not send that data to paypal to just have them send it back to you, you should store it locally, and then send one unique id, when it comes back  use that to retrieve the data

Answer (score 1):

Paypal's custom field only permits 256 characters, your code alone is half of that, so perhaps the variability comes from the different lengthed parameters populated by that code?(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

To be honest, half of that code doesn't need to be in there because paypal also posts those variables to your listener (amount total, product, etc), so taking those out should help your cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right that I can probably cut away many of the parameters sent through "custom", so I might have to give that a shot.

I still don't quite see how it ever exceeds 256 characters, unless there is some encoding going on somewhere. We include name/email in custom field because sometimes they differ from the actual Paypal payers name/email.